# How to use the 'split' command

Tags: shell, split

I have a file with 2000 lines. I am using the following to split the file every 100 lines.

```
split -l 100 file.txt outputfile.txt
```

I would like to add a "FFFFFF" at the end of each file contents, after the split also I would like to specify the extension the file uses, as with the above command the output is as below.

```
outputfile.txtxa, outputfile.txtxb etc...
```

I have read the man page for split and also browsed the web, however I can't find a solution.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean add `FFFFFF` to the file's contents or to the end of the filename?

Comment: @alex To the tail of the contents. Last line.

Comment: `split` is not a Bash command. It is an external utility from the GNU `coreutils` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one pass solution, you could use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR%100==1 { ++i } { print $0 (NR%100==0 ? "\nFFFFFF" : "") > "outputfile" i ".txt" }' file.txt
```

Also, the advantage here is finer control over the output filenames to make them more pretty. Please let me know if you require something more fancy. Cheers.

---

Explanation for [user1937](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1890488/user1937):

If you are familiar with the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), `NR%100==1` will return true for the 1st line, the 101st line, the 201st line, the 301st line etc. Each time it's true, the variable `i` is incremented. Notice how an `awk` statement is made up of condition/action blocks. So `NR%100==1` is the condition and `++i` is the action. What you'll then notice (hopefully) is that the block that has the print action lacks a conditional. Therefore every line of input is being printed (all of the time). The value of `i` simply determines which file the output is being printed to.

Another bit you may not be familiar with is: `(NR%100==0 ? "\nFFFFFF" : "")`. This is a 
[ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) which is shorthand for: `if (NR%100==0) print "\nFFFFFF"; else print "")`. HTH.

---

`awk` code can be built using pattern/action statements in the form:

```
NR%100==1                             # pattern1
{
    ++i                               # action1
}

{
    print $0 ...                      # action2
}
```

As you can see, pattern1 only applies to action1. pattern1 does *not* apply to action2.

Comment: Good old awk. Thanks Steve

Comment: Can you make clear how it will get previous lines before 100 into the file. I am learning awk so wanted to get idea how it works. To me the condition is true at line which are multiple of 100 , so i was thinking only one line will be added to the file

Comment: @user1937: I've added a bit of an explanation. If it is too brief, please let me know. Cheers.

Comment: @steve Doesn't the print $0 statmenet executes when pattern is matched. i was thinking the LHS is the pattern and if that matches then all the RHS code executes. you say that only first brace executes if condition is true not the second brace

Comment: @user1937: No, the `print $0` statement doesn't have a conditional. It's always printing. I've made another update to my answer - it should clear things up :-)

Comment: @steve thanks byddy , i didn't knew that, i thought that pattern was for all statements after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with split alone. This code might help:

```
split -l 100 file.txt outputfile_
find . -name outputfile_\* -exec sh -c 'echo "FFFFFF" >> {} && mv {} {}.txt' \;
```

This will result in files `outputfile_aa.txt`, `outputfileab.txt` etc, which will all end in `FFFFFF`.

This works as follows: first we split the file with prefix `outputfile_` to generate files `outputfile_aa`, `outputfile_ab` etc. Then we invoke the `find` command to gather them all up and execute a command with it. There is a slight problem that you can't use a redirection within the find command, so we'll wrap our redirection into a shell-script and execute the whole thing with `sh`. The `{}` will be replaced by each individual file name (look for `-exec` in `find`'s man page); the script will thus first append the `FFFFFF` string to the end of the file, then rename the file to add the `txt` extension.

Comment: `find` is unnecessary here.  You could just use: `for f in outputfile_*; do echo "FFFFFF" >> "$f"; mv -- "$f" "$f".txt; done`.  Seems simpler.